# PowerApps Survey - Outside users

Tags: powerapps, survey

Can I enable people who are not in my organization to use a PowerApps I created? Planning on creating a quick survey type form in PowerApps but I need to able to share it to people outside our org i.e some vendors we work with. or is there a better way to go about this?

Basically, we want to create a form where people fill out a couple of questions and we store it in a SharePoint list. Regularly I would give permissions to the app for people within out company but I wont be able to in this case

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

you cannot share directly with external user, because every user should have license assigned to them for using power apps.

[look at this MS docs for Guest user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/share-app-guests)

In addition if you want to have survey and it's reponses why don't you look at
[Microsoft Forms](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/online-surveys-polls-quizzes)

you have one more option of [dynamics customer-voice](https://dynamics.microsoft.com/en-us/customer-voice/overview/)

Comment: did you managed to solve this?